# Touchpad scrolling is disabled on Gateway laptop with Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, touchpad, scrolling

Somehow my touchpad scrolling got turned off and I can't figure out how to turn it back on.

I tried the instructions for Windows 7, but the options are different in Windows 8.

Comment: Can you tell us what type of touchpad you have?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install driver software of your touchpad. Then only the scrolling will works in the OS. If you dont have driver software, download it from your laptop brand official site..